# Canvas/Fabric.js interactive drawing don't refresh the graphics with MSHTA.EXE

Tags: batch-file, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs, hta

I think my problem is somewhat unusual. I wrote a Windows Batch .BAT file that read lines from the user (that contains Canvas graphic functions) and send they to a .HTA window through a pipe started via mshta.exe; in the .HTA file the lines are read via `fso.GetStandardStream(0).ReadLine()` and used to draw graphics on the HTA window via `eval()`. Below is the code, but before you start searching for errors, you should know that everything is working correctly excepting for the detail I explain below.

**BatchFile.bat**:

```
@echo off

if "%1" equ "HTA_interface" goto HTA_interface

rem Start interactive drawing; send lines to HTA window via Stderr
"%~F0" HTA_interface 2>&1 1>&3 | mshta.exe "%~DP0\HTAwindow.hta"
goto :EOF


:HTA_interface
   set "canvas="
   set /P "canvas=Canvas function: "
   if not defined canvas goto :EOF
   echo %canvas% >&2
goto HTA_interface
```

**HTAwindow.hta**:

```
<meta http-equiv='x-ua-compatible' content='ie=edge'/>

<HTML>

<HEAD>
<HTA:APPLICATION >
<TITLE>HTA BatchDrawing</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
</BODY>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
   Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag
</canvas>

<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">

var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"),
    stdin = fso.GetStandardStream(0),
    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

window.alert("HTA window started!");

while ( ! stdin.AtEndOfStream ) {
   eval(stdin.ReadLine());
}

</SCRIPT>

</HTML>
```

The goal is that the user enter a graphic function in the cmd.exe window, press Enter and *immediately* see the corresponding graphic in the .HTA window. For example, the user may enter these three lines:

```
ctx.beginPath();ctx.moveTo(0,0);ctx.lineTo(200,100);ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();ctx.lineWidth="10";ctx.strokeStyle="blue";ctx.rect(50,50,150,80);ctx.stroke();
```

**The problem is** that the drawing of each individual graphic *does not happen immediately*: the .HTA window does NOT appear on the screen until the pipe left side terminate, and then the .HTA window appear with all the graphics!

I searched this site an googled for a similar problem, but all related examples and answers refers to interactive graphics created via JavaScript code placed in the same HTML document. I tried the following solutions with no success:

- I installed [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) and used `canvas.renderAll()` method after each individual graphic is drawn. Of course, I used Fabric's equivalent `canvas.add(new fabric.FIG(...))` functions in the Batch file input instead of the normal Canvas ones. Don't works.
- I used the method explained at [Making and Moving Selectable Shapes](http://simonsarris.com/blog/140-canvas-moving-selectable-shapes) tutorial: a `draw()` function is used to refresh the window when there are new graphics, and this function is executed regularly via a `setInterval(draw, INTERVAL)`. Dont't works.

Previous "don't works" means that all versions of the program successfully show all graphics when the input terminate, but don't show individual graphics after each line is sent.

I also tried to insert `window.location.reload()` method after each graphic is drawn, but this just caused an endless loop.

What is the problem here? Is there any way to solve it? TIA